# Alert dialog manger class

Tags: java, android

I want to make a general alert dialog to use across the whole app. I created a class called `AlertDialogManager` and just one method to show `AlertDialog`.

Is there a way to refine my code or this code?

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class AlertDialogManager {
    /**
     * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
     * @param context - application context
     * @param title - alert dialog title
     * @param message - alert message
     * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
     *               - pass null if you don't want icon
     * */
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
            Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `Boolean` for status as a kind of 'ternary type' (`true`, `false`, `null`) feels a little misleading, even if it's documented in the Javadoc.

I would replace it with either three `static final int` constants or an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

### Could be static

Since your dialog manager has no state, I would just make your function `static`.  That way you don't need to create a manager instance just to create a dialog:

```
// Current way:
manager = new AlertDialogManager();
manager.showAlertDialog(/* arguments */);

// Using static function:
AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(/* arguments */);
```